# Capacitor Filesystem API cannot find the relative path?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, react-tsx, ionic-react

(Disclaimer: I am a newbie with React and Ionic) I am looking to implement capacitor's filesystem API into a React Component in order to read a JSON file that contains a simple string. My JSON file is in the same folder as my FileSystem.tsx file.

```
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import { IonHeader, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';
import { IonPage,IonMenuButton,IonButton } from '@ionic/react';


class ReadFileContainer extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
         
    }
}


 readsecretFile = async () => {
  const contents = await Filesystem.readFile({
    path: "file:///Users/tbagggg/Downloads/FinalProject/src/pages/FileSystem/data.json",    
  });
  
  console.log('contents:', contents);
};



 
render() {
  
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>
            This is a test page
          </IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonButton onClick={() => {this.readsecretFile()}}>
      Read File
  </IonButton>
  </IonPage>
  )
}
}

export default ReadFileContainer;
```

However, when I invoke the readsecretFile() method, I am met with this error in google's console.[image: >>>]. The odd thing is, I can CMND click the path in VS Code and it directs me to the file "data.json". Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystem plugin on web platform doesn’t have access to the computer filesystem, it uses IndexedDB to emulate a filesystem storing the files on the database.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I access this emulated file system to add files onto it?

Comment: Would I have to use the writeFile() method?

Comment: writeFile to write, readFile to read. To check the content/files you can use the browser inspection tools, most of them have a storage section with an inner IndexedDB section